# i10n json regex different cases

Tags: json, regex, pattern-matching

So my company needs to send our `i10n` json file to a translator that can translate the thing into other languages.

Now the our system uses this file. Because of this we are able to make some "funky" statements that can be understood by our system but not by our translators when they extract the file.

For instance we have a case like this:

```
    "CHOOSE": "{VALUE, select, 1{Vælg bruger} other{Fejl}}",
```

In the above example our system either takes `Vælg bruger` or `Fejl`

We also have something like this:

```
    "HAS_MATERIAL": "Indeholder {{COUNT}} {{COUNT > 1 ? 'filer' : 'fil'}}",
```

Basicly the result of this would be `Indeholder` and if count is bigger than 1 `filer` else `fil`.

The last case we have is something like this:

```
 "YOU_HAVE_NOTIFICATION": "You have { LENGTH } {LENGTH, select, 1{new notification} other{new notifications}}",
```

Again Length is a temp value and that then decides which translation to take.

So now its my job to make a regex for this file so we can get a list of all the words that need to be translated. and i am rather lost. the above 3 cases has different ways of approaching the wanted value.

i attempted with something like this:

```
{(.*?)}
```

With a global flag

However this doesnt work on all the cases.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use a JSON parser to find the potential strings and then a regex just on those strings. This will make the regex much simpler as it does not need to handle JSON syntax (including things like escaping quote marks).

Comment: In your second example there are double `{}`. In the third, which look similar, there are single `{}`. Are booth these case plausible?

Comment: @ClasG Yes both of these are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are some kind of "command language" (or two) involved this probably will fail at some point, but it handles your given examples:

```
{\w+,\s*select,\s*\w+\s*{([^}]*)}\s\w+\s*{([^}]*)}|{[^?{}]+\?\s*'([^']*)'\s*:\s*'([^']*)'\s*}]*}|^([^{}]+)|([^{}]+)$
```

It treats individual case one by one:

1. The `SELECT` statement

   > Inside braces, expect some `expression` followed by a `,`, a `command` (in this case select), a `,`, a `case value` and here we **grab the text inside braces**. Then expect some other case value and again - **grab the text inside braces**. I expect there will be case were there are more than two cases -> fail. (it can be expanded to handle more though)
2. Then the ternary operator

   > Inside braces, expect some `expression` followed by a `?`, then grab the text inside single quotes**. Then expect a `:` and again - **grab the text inside single quotes**.
3. At the start of a line

   > grab all text up to `{`.
4. And end of line

   > grab anything after last `}`.

I guess this is far from complete. E.g. it won't handle text between "selects", and feels very *fragile*, but it might help you get started.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iY9eQ7/1).